# JS How to set values outside scope with single line

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

if the function `calculateAvgGainLoss` response includes `avgGain, avgLoss` we can get these values like this.

```
const { avgGain, avgLoss } = calculateAvgGainLoss(prices);
```

I want to set these values to the variable that defined outside of the function. How can I do that ? Example below.

```
describe("test", () => {
  let avgGain: number, avgLoss: number;
  it("Calculate average gain & loss", () => {
    const prices = [...];
    /*...This isn't working, has to be changed...*/ { avgGain, avgLoss } = calculateAvgGainLoss(prices);
    expect(avgGain).toBe(0.24);
    expect(avgLoss).toBe(0.1);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning the line by a `{` confuses parsers (is it the beginning of a scope? an object? etc). Just bypass this by wrapping your line with parenthesis:

```
describe("test", () => {
  let avgGain: number, avgLoss: number;
  it("Calculate average gain & loss", () => {
    const prices = [...];
    ({ avgGain, avgLoss } = calculateAvgGainLoss(prices)); // <--
    expect(avgGain).toBe(0.24);
    expect(avgLoss).toBe(0.1);
  });

});
```

Comment: Actually I had tried exactly this way before asking but this time I am getting ' Variable '.....' is used before being assigned' error.

Comment: I don't understand - please provide a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) link

Comment: It worked as expected. My mistake sorry. Thank you for your help